# Using aio_write and write at the same time

Tags: c, linux

Consider I called `aio_write()` to write large portion of file asynchronously. Then program continued to execute and called `write()`. 
Flag `NON_BLOCK` is not set.
Will write() wait until aio_write() is finished? Is it correct to mix `write()` and `aio_write()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `write()` will not wait for `aio_write()` to finish. However, practically - depending upon filesystem, load on a machine, size of IO -   you may see that `write()` finishes after `aio_write()`. But there is no guarantee that write issued first will finish first.

Mixing `aio_write()` and `write()` is fine if they do not write to same blocks. If they overlap, you will have to handle all cases of which IO completed first, bit more complicated.